# How to avoid an excess byte when a structure contains a byte variable? (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, byte

VB.NET 4.5

I have a structure defined that includes a single byte. I need to get an array of bytes to be sent over a Serial port.

```
Public Structure ExampleStructure
    Public variable1 As Byte
    Public variable2 As UInt16
    Public variable3 As UInt16

    Public Function getBytes() As Byte()
        Dim binaryBytes(5) As Byte
        Dim pointerCommand As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Me, pointerCommand, False)
        Marshal.Copy(pointerCommand, binaryBytes, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointerCommand)
        Return binaryBytes
    End Function
End Structure
```

The issue is :

when I use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, `Marshal.StructureToPtr`, and `Marshal.Copy`, the byte array returned is 6 bytes. .NET creates 2 bytes for variable1, so there is an excess byte between variable1 and variable2 data.

I can resolve this by using a `LayoutKind.Explicit` and defining FieldOffsets.

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
Public Structure ExampleStructure
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public variable1 As Byte
    <FieldOffset(1)> Public variable2 As UInt16
    <FieldOffset(3)> Public variable3 As UInt16

    Public Function getBytes() As Byte()
        Dim binaryBytes(5) As Byte
        Dim pointerCommand As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Me, pointerCommand, False)
        Marshal.Copy(pointerCommand, binaryBytes, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointerCommand)
        Return binaryBytes
    End Function
End Structure
```

Now when I get the bytes, there is no longer an excess byte between variable1 and variable2.

This seems like a clunky way to do this though. Is there a better option where I don't have to manually set FieldOffsets? This structure is simple, but they can get far more complicated.

Comment: The compiler is trying to optimize the code by aligning data on 16 bit boundary.  So you are fighting the compiler optimizer.  Microprocessors these days run faster when codes are aligned on wider boundaries.  Not sure if there is a compiler option to force code to align on byte boundaries.  Try : LayoutKind.Sequential

Comment: I just tried LayoutKind.Sequential, but no luck.

Comment: Try pack option : [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack = 8)]

Comment: <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> was the magic tag, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The fix was very simple - just need to add the tag LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> _
Public Structure ExampleStructure
    Public variable1 As Byte
    Public variable2 As UInt16
    Public variable3 As UInt16

    Public Function getBytes() As Byte()
        Dim binaryBytes(5) As Byte
        Dim pointerCommand As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Me, pointerCommand, False)
        Marshal.Copy(pointerCommand, binaryBytes, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(Me))
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointerCommand)
        Return binaryBytes
    End Function
End Structure
```